# Google Client Library For .NET

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm using [Google Client Library For .NET (v1.9.0.1360)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.youtube.v3/) to search for Youtube videos. I'm trying to understand how I should handle errors from Youtube. As far as I can tell, the only exception I can catch from the library is `GoogleApiException` which only contains `HttpStatusCode`. However, looking at [the possible error codes](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors) that Youtube can return, there are several cases where the same code is used, with a different message, to differentiate between errors.

How can I tell if I receive a `400 - invalidPageToken` or `400 - missingRequiredParameter`? The `Message` property of `GoogleApiException` looks like this, but how am I supposed to parse that?

```
Message = "Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError\r\nBad Request [400]\r\nErrors [\r\n\tMessage[Bad Request] Location[pageToken - parameter] Reason[invalidPageToken] Domain[youtube.parameter]\r\n]\r\n"
```

Comment: You might want to add a comment and click the star to vote for [Issue 480](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/detail?id=480).

Comment: * We moved to github, so it's actually - https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/480. So issue 480, you want to be able to include data from the error (e.g. domain, reason, etc.), right?

Comment: @peleyal, thanks. Yeah, I'm looking for a way to get more information about the error. More than the http status code

Comment: We will try to include it in our next version. Thanks for reporting.